# Naked domain to "www" redirect in Windows Server 2008

Tags: redirects, dns, url-rewriting, iis7, windows-server-2008

I have a Windows server. I have several websites hosted on my server. Currently, I can only visit these websites if I include "www" (e.g., `www.techtint.com`).

I want the naked form of the URL to redirect to the `www` URL. I don't want a duplicate version of the website, but just want to permanently re-direct all the traffic to the naked URL to `www.mysite.com`.

I know it has something to do with `A` records and `CNAME` record, but it is all very confusing. Can someone explain to me in details on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

**`Currently, I can only visit these websites if I include www. Eg:www.techtint.com`**

It appears that your DNS configuration has some issues: As indicated in the DNS health reports below, the nameservers for your domain are not resolving properly, and there are no `MX` (mailserver) records either. It does appear that you have `A` and `CNAME` records for the `www` subdomain however:

[DNS health check](http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=techtint.com)

[DNS health full report](http://www.intodns.com/techtint.com)

Therefore, I would suggest working with your DNS provider (e.g., your domain registrar, webhosting/ISP company, or third-party DNS service) to resolve these DNS issues first.

**`I want the naked form of the URL to redirect to www.`**

If you want the root domain (`techtint.com`) to be accessible but redirected to the `www` subdomain, first you'll need to have an `A` record for the root domain that points to the same IP address as the `A` record for the `www` subdomain does (i.e., `96.127.134.97`).

Next you'll want to add your root domain as a site in IIS7 as detailed in the steps here: [Create a new site in IIS 7](http://www.hosting.com/support/iis7/create-new-sites-in-iis-7)

After your root domain is reachable from a browser (note that it can take up to 72 hours for DNS changes to propagate throughout the Internet), you'll want to redirect the root domain to the `www` subdomain as covered here:  [IIS URL Rewrite – rewriting non-www to www](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/11/27/iis-url-rewrite-rewriting-non-www-to-www.aspx)

Comment: You shouldn't need to create a separate site in IIS for the root domain and then redirect it, you can do all of that with one site: Set up the site to respond on both `techint.com` and `www.techint.com` host headers, and then use the URL Rewrite Module to enable the "Canonical Domain Name" template in the [SEO Rule Templates](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/seo-rule-templates) section.

Comment: Not sure if the net results would be any different, but maybe you can explain _how_ to do this for the OP and the benefits.