# Should I use IIS or my DNS provider to redirect my naked domain to its www version?

Tags: domains, redirects, dns, iis, no-www

How do I get the naked domain for my site that is typed into a browser (`example.com`) to automatically redirect to `www.mywebsite.com`. Would this be done on the internal IIS web server or through the registration service DNS settings?

I use `Register.com` and I tried asking their technical support, but they did not answer my question with a usable solution.

Comment: You would use both: First create a DNS record for the `www` subdomain as covered in the second part of the answer [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52144/naked-domain-to-www-redirect-in-windows-server-2008/52178#52178), then create a redirect rule for IIS as covered in this answer [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56296/canonicalization-for-www-non-www-urls-and-ip-domain-on-a-windows-server/56309#56309). You can also do the later using a _web.config_ file as William covered in his answer.

Comment: Off topic, but may I ask why you chose register.com ?

Answer (score 1):

> Would this be done on the internal IIS web server

It's possible. There are several ways. I will show the way where you use the `web.config` file. In your `web.config` file put the following code:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect domain.com to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain.com" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Or if you want to use regular expressions:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect domain.com to www" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.com$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just try editing .htaccess file.

Just paste the following code in .htaccess file

```
#Force www:
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

replace "example" with "your domain name".

Comment: The OP is asking about IIS, not Apache.